# What is the best way to initialize a let property that has a closure on self in Swift?

Tags: swift

As you may know the initialization rules in Swift a pretty strict (too strict if you ask me). I find myself in the situation of having to initialize a let property that requires a closure on self and of course the compailer complains. Something like the following example.

```
let aString: String
let delete: Action<Int, Int, NoError>

init(aString: String) {
  self.aString = aString
  self.delete = Action { [unowned self](index) in 
    return self.performDeletion(index)
  }
}

func performDeletion(index: Int) -> SignalProduer<Int, NoError> {
  // Some deletion logic
}
```

The only "solution" I found was to use a private variable like this

```
let aString: String

private let _delete: Action<Int, Int, NoError>
var delete: Action<Int, Int, NoError> {
  return _delete!
}

init(aString: String) {
  self.aString = aString
  _delete = Action { [unowned self](index) in 
    return self.performDeletion(index)
  }
}

func performDeletion(index: Int) -> SignalProduer<Int, NoError> {
  // Some deletion logic
}
```

Are there any other solutions?